# Is $\frac{x^2+y^2}{(x+y)^2} \geq \frac{1}{2} \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: inequality

This inequality came up in something I'm working on and I've had no luck finding an approach so far. I'm fairly sure it holds though after looking at some plots.

Comment: Your inequality is the same as $(x-y)^2 \ge 0$.

Comment: @ArcticChar provided that $y\neq -x$ ;)

Comment: Why is this downvoted?  Yes, user844177 could show more work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let at least one of x and y not be zero.

$ 0\leq (x-y)^2$ See **

$2xy \leq x^2+y^2$

$\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}\leq 1$  then add to both sides and simplify LHS

$\frac{x^2+2xy+y^2}{x^2+y^2} \leq2$  then take reciprocal both sides

$\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+2xy+y^2} \geq \frac12$  Note: The reciprocal requires both sides be positive.



Note: Deriving this proof is not hard if we 
A. Start with $\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+2xy+y^2} \geq \frac12$**
B. Simplify everything down to a known inequality.
C. Recopy reversing all the steps.
Obviously, A, is not valid in an actual proof, but these steps for deriving proofs, and leaving A and B out of the final proof, can be very helpful, especially for epsilon delta proofs.
Of course check for irreversible steps.

Comment: yeah, i got it thanks man